# How to move object to arrangement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

everyone

I got a question , I want to implement a UI , Like iOS desktop , so far I can arrangement

objects via the code below :

```
int k=0;
    int j;
    for (int i=0; i<[items count]; i++) {
       //k is row     
        j=i%3;
        if (j==0) {
            k++;
            if (k%3 == 1) {
                k = 1;
            }
        }
 [button setFrame:CGRectMake(25+(i%3*95), 35+((k-1)*140), 100, 100)];
```

So , The view will looks like this

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

Now , let it into edit mode ,  drag A drop between E and F

So there are many things need to do

B and C will shift to left , D will go up after B C

E shift left .(how to implement these animations ???)

```
B C D
E A F
G H I
```

I search the Apple sample , I only find Moveme this sample , but it only one object

Any advise or sample code will be great help : )

Thanks

Webber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user moves a button, you have to find it's new index first.

```
int j = (button.frame.origin.x - 25) / 95;
int k = (button.frame.origin.x - 35) / 140;
int newIndex = 3 * k + j;
```

Then you have to place it at that index in the items array.

```
[items insertObject:button atIndex:newIndex];
```

Then you should call the code you provided to reposition the buttons.

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.count; i++) {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[items objectAtIndex:i];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
       button.frame = CGRectMake(25+(i%3)*95, 35+(i/3)*140, 100, 100); 
    }];
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean , I will try your code : )
How do I know which button has been modified ???

Comment: Ok , It list items with animations ,now I need to move object .

Comment: The math is probably not correct, I didn't test it. But you get the idea I hope.

Comment: Thanks @sch let me try to get the new index .