# Animation like rearranging app icons after one is deleted

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, core-animation

When an application is deleted from an iOS device, that particular icon gets removed and all other app icons get re-arranged -- moved one place left.

I want to do a similar thing: I'll have a 3x3 grid. When I touch any of the items, that one will get deleted and all the others will perform the animation as when an app icon has been deleted.

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move object to arrangement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287341/how-to-move-object-to-arrangement)

Comment: @Josh - Not a duplicate. Please check the descriptions of both the questions again. (And there are no accepted answers of that question too.)

Comment: I am able to create Tiles and on touchesBegan I can perform wiggling of the tiles. After this I am clueless how to delete it and re-arrange all the grids/tiles again.

Comment: Probably because the question is vague. You question is essentially "show me the code" which is frowned upon here. You are much more likely to receive answers if you try some solutions on your own, fail and then ask "why did my approach fail". In any case, I answered your question below, which is to use AQGridView. It provides an easy way to lay out stuff in grids and animate insertions, deltions, rotations, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is AQGridView which can be [found on github](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). It provides animations for reordering and orientation changes. Fairly easy to implement too. Look at the included Springboard example. Here is a video of AQGridView animating orientation changes: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPwY1HHRQJ8

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do it is to layout the tiles in `layoutSubviews`. In this method you arrange the tiles according to their count and order. When you need to add, remove or re-arrange the tiles, just modify the model and send the collection view `setNeedsLayout` and then `layoutIfNeeded` inside an animation block.

This solution requires subclassing `UIView`, but in most similar cases you have to do it anyway.

Comment: :-Thanks for the response. I am not getting the exact idea with this, can you provide some tutorial/testCode for this. It'd be very helpful.

Comment: The first example that comes to my mind is `AQGrid`. It may look complicated, but the basic idea is the same: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/blob/master/Classes/AQGridView.m